# React use custom hook function

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want use custom hook function

**custom hook code**

```
import { useState, useCallback, useEffect } from 'react';
import { apiClient } from './apiClient';

export default (api: string) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState();

  const getData = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      const response = await apiClient.get(api);
      setData(response.data);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }, [data]);

  return [data, getData];
};
```

**app code**

```
const [data, getData] = useGetData('posts');

  useEffect(() => {
    getData(); <- error
  }, []);
```

**error message**

Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2722)

How can use custom hook function ?

Comment: What's  the error it's giving you ?

Comment: Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2722)
this error message...

Answer (score 2):

You will need to explicitly type the function to return a 2-tuple, since TypeScript can't perfectly infer that. It infers an array.

```
export default (api: string): [any, () => void] => {
```

(or a better type than `any`, but I don't know what your API returns.)

To improve typing, you might want to make it a generic function:

```
import { useState, useCallback } from "react";

export default function useGetData<T>(api: string): [T | undefined, () => void] {
  const [data, setData] = useState<T | undefined>(undefined);
  const getData = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      const response = await apiClient.get(api);
      setData(response.data as T);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }, [data]);
  return [data, getData];
}
```